# Ruby / nanoc: How do I get a list of items to display in a page?

Tags: ruby, nanoc

I fully admit I am a [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) newb, and this question could come simply out of my ignorance for Ruby.

That being said, I'm getting started with the [nanoc project](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/) (and loving it).  I'd like to power my blog using this ... but: For the life of me, **I can't figure out how to get a list of articles / posts to display on the main page.  How do I do this?**

*I'd like to use erb/html if possible.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some erb that creates a list of 10 most recent articles with the title, date and links. You can also add the article content using `article.compiled_content`. I use hpricot to display only the fist paragraph of each post in my [blog](http://mpastell.com/blog)

```
<% @site.sorted_articles[0, 10].each do |article| %>
<p><strong> 
<%= link_to(article[:title], article.path) %> </strong><br/>
<%= article[:created_at] %> <br/>
<%= tags_for(article) %> <br/></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Nanoc3::Helpers::Blogging` there are methods called `articles` and `sorted_articles` (see http://nanoc.stoneship.org/docs/api/3.1/Nanoc3/Helpers/Blogging.html).

You can "enable" that helper using

```
include Nanoc3::Helpers::Blogging
```

in a file in `lib/` like `lib/helpers.rb`.

See http://nanoc.stoneship.org/docs/4-basic-concepts/#helpers

Comment: If there's no file like that in your `lib/` directory. Just created one and paste the line above in that file. Nanoc will require every file in `lib/` so you may add it to one of the others as well or create another file with an arbitrary name.

Comment: I think @DanEsparza meant an example of using the sorted_articles method after you've included the Blogging helper.